# Clickable html links in Python 3.6 shell?

Tags: python, shell, clickable

Say, I have a list full of html links that looks something like this:

`https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/19/realestate/they-can-afford-to-buy-but-they-would-rather-rent.html`

When I run a script in Python 3.6 Idle, I get the list as an output in Python 3.6 shell; however, they are not clickable.  Is there a simple way to make them clickable in the shell?

I've googled around but I can't seem to find anything involving the Python shell.

Thank you.

Comment: That's a limitation of the shell in general. It's a text interface. Clicking isn't a "thing".

Comment: I don't know if this will help you at all, but there is the `webbrowser` module that will let you launch your default web browser at a provided URL.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419276/python-how-to-print-text-to-console-as-hyperlink

Comment: @aryamccarthy I see.  What options do I have? Jupyter Notebook allows me to have an output of clickable links. Besides this, any suggestion as to what I should look into?

Comment: @FamousJameous   Yeah, I know about `webrowser` but I think I would have to create a GUI, to do the whole "click to launch" right?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000   That link seems to be referring to output of command prompt, which is not what I'm asking.

Comment: @Moondra did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 10):

## Auto-linking terminals

It depends on the terminal you're using. Some terminals have configurable rules (mostly regexes) that will recognise links in your tools' output and make them clickable.

See

- https://iterm2.com/documentation-smart-selection.html
- https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/v0.8.0/docs/features.md#opening-urls-with-the-mouse

## Custom links

Some terminals also let you create custom links via special [shell escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

Since you mentioned py3.6, I'm using f-strings:

```
text = "This is a link"
target = "http://example.com"
print(f"\u001b]8;;{target}\u001b\\{text}\u001b]8;;\u001b\\")
```

This will make a clickable link in some terminals. (iTerm2, Gnome Terminal or even iPython running in one of these terminals.) It doesn't seem to work in Alacritty and Kitty, however.

To learn more about hyperlink escape sequences, see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda) or this blog post https://purpleidea.com/blog/2018/06/29/hyperlinks-in-gnome-terminal/

[image: ipython example of hyperlinks]

Comment: not working on python 3 , I only get a text 'This is a link" but its not a link

Comment: @Tokci It's got nothing to do with python versions. Your terminal has to support the feature. I've only tried a few like iTerm2 & Gnome Terminal. I just tested Kitty & Alacritty and it doesn't work in these.

Comment: Ok I see ..I did it on bash on windows.

Comment: Related for PyCharm console: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300594/print-code-link-into-pycharms-console

Comment: There is a shorter alternative `print(f"\x1b]8;;{target}\a{text}\x1b]8;;\a")`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. No. IDLE is the most basic of editors and the shell is just that.